# Relative Clause Sentences I have a lot of work to do

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses, clauses, relative-pronouns, reduced-relative-clauses

I have a lot of work to do. =  I have a lot of work that I must do.

It is the same. I can't understand that. How?

Comment: Try it in this order: I have to do a lot of work. That means I am obligated to perform many tasks = I have many tasks that I am obligated to perform.

Comment: The meanings aren't *identical*. Consider *I have a lot of **food to eat***. That would usually be understood to mean a lot of food which I ***can*** eat, which isn't the same as having a lot of food that I ***must*** eat. Syntactically speaking, ***work to do*** and ***food to eat*** are the same - it's just that we tend to assume doing work is something you only do because you *must*, whereas you're more likely to eat food because you *can*.

Answer (score 1):

> *I have a lot of work* [*to do*].

The bracketed element is an infinitival **relative clause** modifying "lot of work".

Infinitival relative clauses like this have a **modal** meaning comparable to that expressed in finite clauses by "can or "should". Your example is comparable to

> *I have a lot of work that I should do.*

Answer (score 0):

In

> I have a lot of work to do.

the infinitive *to do* modifies *a lot of work* to form a noun phrase.

It means almost the same as

> I have a lot of work that I must do.

where the relative clause *that I must do* modifies *a lot of work*.

Using *must* in the second sentence is valid as *work* is usually perceived as something we do only because it's a must.  If we use **food** in the first sentence, the modal verb in the second sentence would likely be **can**.  Please refer to @FumbleFingers' comments.

More flexible would be

> ... **many things** to do

> ... many things that I **must** (or **can**) do.

Please note not all infinitives modify their preceding nouns to form noun phrases.  In

> The project needed money **to be completed**.

The infinitive *to be completed* is an "adverbial expression indicating the purpose of all the words before, and is movable to the start of the sentence".  We can also insert **in order**:

> The project needed money **in order to be completed**.

The infinitive here does not modify *money*.

> *money to be completed